# ROS : Performing 2-D Pedestrian Dead Reckoning on an AR Drone and displaying location on a floorplan

Tags: localization, ros, dead-reckoning

I'm trying to find a way where I can estimate the location of my drone on a floorplan. Note that right now, I will just be moving the drone around manually and not flying it.

I read up on PDR and what I want to do is this:
Provide an initial location of my drone on the floorplan, and as I move the drone around, using information from the IMU/accelerometers, I want to update the position of my drone on the floorplan.

I've worked with ROS a bit and I want to know if there are packages in ROS that could do this. For now, I'm looking for rough estimates and not perfect solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* ReiJin ThunderKeg, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site, even shopping for package recommendations. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0):

> using information from the IMU/accelerometers

These sensors will accumulate error and will not provide a good estimate of the position of the drone after some time.

What you need is some absolute reference point. You need to make some kind of connection between the sensor data and the surrounding area that you are trying to localise yourself in. Check out [slam](/questions/tagged/slam), which is the general term used for this kind of stuff. If you know the environment and already have a map, the task simplifies to [localization](/questions/tagged/localization), but a few of the things from slam might still apply.

Comment: For an initial exploratory step, I am okay with the drift accumulation. I just want to see my position updates on a given floorplan, no matter how erroneous it seems. Is there some sort of ROS package that helps me do this?