# Using an AR.Drone's IMU to perform PDR

Tags: quadcopter, localization, imu, dead-reckoning

My task is simple: I want to move my drone manually around a room (**IMPORTANT: I DO NOT WANT TO FLY IT**) and I want to see its position update on a map using IMU data.

I've attempted something in ROS and Rviz, but the position on the map does not update when I pickup my drone from spot A and place it 5 meters away at spot B. It does however update when I fly the drone from A to B.

My question is this : is there someway I can do dead reckoning using the drone while not flying it? Or is flying the drone necessary to perform dead reckoning using the drone's IMU?

EDIT: Here's what my Rviz shows when I pickup the drone from A and put it at B. As you can see, orientation is updated, but the position remains the same. However, when I fly the drone, I can see the red arrow move around the map.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT : The duplicate question just asks for general solutions. Here I've found a solution, I just can't get it to work; I need help debugging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ROS : Performing 2-D Pedestrian Dead Reckoning on an AR Drone and displaying location on a floorplan](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/10714/ros-performing-2-d-pedestrian-dead-reckoning-on-an-ar-drone-and-displaying-loc)

Comment: The other question has been closed as a shopping question, since it was seeking a ROS package recommendation, and this one appears more practical and relevant to the site anyway.